# Confused about complex class structure and Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Been getting into Knockout and and slowly getting used to it. Trying to use it in a new project, but am having a hard time getting things lined up to work. While I understand and can do simple examples (simple form with text boxes bound to ko.observables, or a table or list bound to a ko.observableArray), I can't get the syntax right for a combination, especially if I want to convert the data to JSON format in order to transmit it, via a webservice, to be saved into a database.

Basically it's a data entry form, with some text entry boxes, then a list of items (think company information + a list of it's employees).

I have a sample Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rhzu6/

In the saveData function, I just don't know what to do to get the data packaged. Doing ko.toJS(self) just shows "Object".

I tried defining the data as objects, but quickly got lost:

```
function Company(CompanyName, ZipCode) {

    var self = this;
    self.ZipCode = ko.observable(ZipCode);
    self.CompanyName = ko.observable(CompanyName );
    self.Employees = ko.observableArray();
}

function Employee(FirstName, LastNameB) {
    var self = this;
    self.FirstName = ko.observable(FirstName);
    self.LastName = ko.observable(LastName);
}
```

Then the ViewModel looked like:

```
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Company = ko.observable(); // company?
    self.Employees = ko.observableArray(); // ?
}
```

But ran into the same issue. And also had binding problems - data-bind:"value: CompanyName" threw an exception saying it didn't know what CompanyName was...

Color me stumped. I'm sure it's something easy that I'm just missing.

Any and all help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: You should post your html markup

Comment: It's in the jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `ko.toJSON` which will first call ko.toJS on your ViewModel and afterwards `JSON.stringify`.

`ko.toJS` will convert your knockout model to a simple JavaScript object, hence replacing all observables etc. with their respective values.

I updated your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rhzu6/2/) to demonstrate.

For more info, take a look at this [post](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html) from Ryan Niemeyers blog.

An alternative is to make use of `ko.utils.postJson`:

```
ko.utils.postJson(location.href, {model: ko.toJS(viewModel) });
```

Notice the `ko.toJS` again.

Comment: It's not so much which to JSON function to call, it's what to pass to it. In the viewModel's self.saveData function returns: "ReferenceError: viewModel is not defined"

Comment: It depends where you declare your save method. In case the save method is defined on the viewModel you can just pass self or this to the toJSON method.

Comment: Well, I don't know what I did before, but I changed my actual code to more match the jsFiddle... and doing ko.toJSON(self) in the self.saveData function (which is declared in the viewModel) DOES do the right thing. As I said, probably did something dumb. However, trying to add a new Employee doesn't add a new row to the table... Thanks though!

Comment: I linked an updated version of your fiddle in my answer. Your add method is not doing anything, it's just pushing 'undefined' onto your array

Comment: I also updating the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/johnt519/rhzu6/3/ with my own dumb mistake - Have to do self.Employees.push(new Employee());  the push on the Employees without the ()'s (I also added the Employee class so KO knows what to do). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if you (semantically) want to submit a form. Therefore, I think that you should use the [submit binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/submit-binding.html). The biggest benefit is that you listen to the submit event, which allows submit by other means, such as Ctrl+Enter or any other keyboard combination you want.

Here is an example on how that submitEvent handler could look like. Note that it uses [ko.mapper](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html), which is a great way to create a viewModel from any JS/JSON-object you want. Typically, you would have

**[backend model]** -> *serialization* -> **[JS/JSON-ojbect]** -> *ko.mapper.fromJSON(obj)* -> **knockout wired viewModel**.

```
viewModel.submitEvent = function () {
    if (viewModel.isValid()) { //if you are using knockout validate
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: '/MyBackend/Add',
                contentType: 'application/json',    
                type: 'POST',
                data: ko.mapping.toJSON(viewModel.entityToValidateOnBackend),
                success: function (result) {
                    ko.mapping.fromJSON(result, viewModel);
                }
            }
        );
    }
};
```

Good luck!

Comment: I will have to look into that. The other wrinkle that I didn't add, to not complicate it more, is this is all withing a custom DotNetNuke module, which is contained within a page in a DNN site, so capturing the Submit may (or may not) be an issue (wonderful .NET, play nice or else ;) )  Thanks.

Comment: Well, using this method would require adding a binding on the FORM element (<form data-bind="submit: doSomething">) - but being a .NET / DNN site, I don't have access to the FORM element, DNN adds it to the page. Thanks again.